# Рефакторинг части кода в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Каким образом можно в IDE заменить часть кода таким образом, например я решил ввести

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=view.getZPJPanel().getPeriodDTM();
```

Как во всем коде поменять на dtm все view.getZPJPanel().getPeriodDTM();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сделать замену через Ctrl+R